# Select Details with Calculated Totals

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm use following SQL Script

```
SELECT PettyHeader.HPetDate,
PettyHeader.HPetVouNo,
PettyHeader.HPetPayee,
PettyDetail.DPetAcNo,
PettyDetail.DPetDetail,
PettyDetail.DPetAmount
FROM PettyHeader
INNER JOIN PettyDetail
ON PettyHeader.HPetComCode = PettyDetail.DPetComCode AND
PettyHeader.HPetLocCode = PettyDetail.DPetLocCode AND
PettyHeader.HPetDate = PettyDetail.DPetDate AND
PettyHeader.HPetVouNo = PettyDetail.DPetVouNo
WHERE (PettyHeader.HPetComCode = '15') AND
(PettyHeader.HPetLocCode = '01') AND
(PettyHeader.HPetDate = CONVERT(DATE, '20180711', 111))
union  all
SELECT PettyDetail.DPetDate,
    PettyDetail.DPetVouNo,
    '',
    '',
    '',
    sum(PettyDetail.DPetAmount)
    FROM PettyDetail
    WHERE (PettyDetail.DPetComCode = '15') AND
    (PettyDetail.DPetLocCode = '01') AND
    (PettyDetail.DPetDate = CONVERT(DATE, '20180711', 111))
    group by PettyDetail.DPetDate,
    PettyDetail.DPetVouNo
```

I want to display Header Table records with  Details Table records. its ok. But I want to display sub total also.
My actual requirment display as follow
[image]

But my result shows 
[image]

how i solve my problem by displaying as first image.

Comment: You could probably add something like an `ORDER BY HPetVouNo` after those unioned selects. But starko's answer has a point. If you would add a tag for the type of database you're using then perhaps a ROLLUP could be used for this.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle and SQL Server you can use **ROLLUP**. All information you should find in this [link](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets)

Link is about Oracle, but ROLLUP work exactly this same in SQL Server.

Comment: I'm Using SQL 2008 when i'm using ROLLUP its shows error - The CUBE() and ROLLUP() grouping constructs are not allowed in the current compatibility mode. They are only allowed in 100 mode or higher. How to solve this error.

Comment: alternative use GROUPING and GROUPING SETS or you can change database settings for example: ALTER DATABASE dbname SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100